# Is there a way to vectorize this for loop

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Is there a way to vectorize this for loop to speed up?

thank you

```
        for j =1 :size(Rond_Input2Cell,1)

            for k=1: size(Rond_Input2Cell,2)

                Rond_Input2Cell(j,k)=  (Pre_Rond_Input2Cell(j,k)*Y_FGate(k))+(net_Cell(k)*Y_InGate(k)*tmp_input(j)) ;

            end
        end
```

P.s.

Matrix size:

Rond_Input2Cell =39*120

Pre_Rond_Input2Cell = 39*120

Y_FGate=1*120      (row vector)

net_Cell=1*120      (row vector)

Y_InGate =1*120     (row vector)

tmp_input =1*39     (row vector)

Comment: are input2cell and net cell of type cell or matrix?

Comment: @Finn: these are matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed up this calculation without using a `for loop` but instead using `bsxfun` which uses memory to speed up the processing 
This code below perform the same function row by row and adds them

```
 Rond_Input2Cell = bsxfun(@times,tmp_input.' ,net_Cell.*Y_InGate) +  bsxfun(@times ,Pre_Rond_Input2Cell,Y_FGate);
```

**Exlpanation :**

```
Pre_Rond_Input2Cell(j,k)*Y_FGate(k)
```

This is performed by using `bsxfun(@times ,Pre_Rond_Input2Cell,Y_FGate)` which mutiplies each 39 rows of Pre_Rond_Input2Cell with 120 columns of `Y_FGate`

`net_Cell(k)*Y_InGate(k)*tmp_input(j)`  is replaced by   `bsxfun(@times,tmp_input.' ,net_Cell.*Y_InGate)` which mutiplies each element of `tmp_input` with dot mutiplication of `net_Cell` and `Y_InGate`In the end the it is stored in `Rond_Input2Cell`

Here is a performance check

```
>> perform_check
Elapsed time is 0.000475 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000156 seconds.
>> perform_check
Elapsed time is 0.001089 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000288 seconds.
```

One more Method is to use `repmat`

```
tic;
    Rond_Input2Cell =(Pre_Rond_Input2Cell.*repmat(Y_FGate,size(Pre_Rond_Input2Cell,1),1)) + (repmat(tmp_input.',1,size(Pre_Rond_Input2Cell,2)).*repmat(net_Cell.*Y_InGate,size(Pre_Rond_Input2Cell,1),1));
    toc;
```

Here is a performance test with a `for` loop

```
>> perf_test
Elapsed time is 0.003268 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.001719 seconds.
>> perf_test
Elapsed time is 0.004211 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.002348 seconds.
>> perf_test
Elapsed time is 0.002384 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000509 seconds.
```

[Here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/) is an article by Loren on Performance of `repmat` vs `bsxfun`

Comment: thanx for your answer, but when i run it, it is not much faster than for loop, when I run it  elapesed time is 0.000125 seconds while for loop elsaped time is 0.000168 seconds. would you please guide me what bsxfun do and is there a way which is faster than bsxfun

Comment: You can get correct time If you averagefor mutiple runs, bsxfun stands for binary singleton expansion It uses memory to speed up the process instead of an iteration

Comment: Here are 2 blogs which explains the performance of bsxfun as compared to a for loop http://blog.accelereyes.com/blog/2010/04/05/converting-matlab-loops-to-gpu-code/

Comment: Here is one more http://matlabtidbits.blogspot.co.at/2013/10/vectorization-via-singleton-expansion.html

Comment: now I accepted this answer, is there any way to accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your vectorized  code should be something like this.

`temp_mat = tmp_input' * (net_Cell .* Y_InGate)` -  size (39*120)

`Rond_Input2Cell =  (Pre_Rond_Input2Cell .* Y_FGate) .+ temp_mat` -  size (39*120)

Comment: thank you for answering, but this runs with errorr "Matrix dimensions must agree."